# Weird error when parsing ISO 8601 Date in java

Tags: java, scala, date, iso8601

I have this snippet of code in Scala, using [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) from Java:

```
val ISO8601Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss")
ISO8601Format.setLenient(false)

val currentDate = new Date()
val str = ISO8601Format.format(currentDate)
val dateParsed = ISO8601Format.parse(str)
val dateParsed2 = ISO8601Format.parse(str)
val dateParsed3 = ISO8601Format.parse(str)

println(currentDate.getTime)             // 1429124862000
println(dateParsed.getTime)              // 1429124862157
println(dateParsed2.getTime)      // 1429124862000
println(dateParsed3.getTime)     // 1429124862000
```

The [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is different that the standard because I am implementing a modified version without offset-from-UTC because XML-RPC (the protocol I am implementing) uses this format.

The problem is that the first parsed date always returns a different value (the last three digits are different) than the initial date (currentDate).  However, if you parse the same string formatted more times, they always return the initial date that it is supposed to return.

Why? A bug? Any idea to fix it up?

(I am doing a library for Scala, and I have to support Java Dates, please do not recommend [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).)

Comment: That looks very odd - can you reproduce it with a short but complete program in Java? Are you using the format in multiple threads?

Comment: Could it be because you are parsing in a string with seconds, but you are outputting in milliseconds. The milliseconds (last 3 digits) value is for when the currentDate was instantiated. This does not explain the output for dateParsed2 and dateParsed3 though.

Comment: Yes, @Sanj, I thought it was that, but when I check dateParsed2 and dateParsed3 that didn't make sense.

Comment: @JonSkeet How do you want me to reproduce it? If you want, I can do a gist with the correct imports.

Comment: I am not using it in multiple threads @JonSkeet, that gist is on its way

Comment: A date-time string without an offset-from-UTC *does* comply with ISO 8601, contrary to the 2nd paragraph in the Question. Such a string is interpreted as a "local date-time" meaning a date-time that applies to any particular locality rather than a point on the timeline of history. Example: Christmas starts at the stroke of midnight on December 25, 2015, `2015-12-25T00:00:00.000`, a different moment in each locality for their particular midnight.

Comment: Also, don't conflate a [time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) with an [offset-from-UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). A time zone is an offset plus info such as Daylight Saving Time and other anomalies (past, present, and future).

Answer (score 0):

> I have to support Java Dates, please do not recommend Joda-Time.

Actually, you *can* use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) while remaining compatible with java.time.Date.

Do the heavy-lifting with Joda-Time or java.time. Then, at the end, convert to a java.util.Date.

Example in Joda-Time 2.7.

```
String input = "20150123T12:34:56";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss" ).withZoneUTC();
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( input );
```

Now convert from Joda-Time to java.util.Date.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();  // Easily convert to a java.util.Date instance.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "date: " + date );
```

When run.

```
input: 20150123T12:34:56
dateTime: 2015-01-23T12:34:56.000Z
date: Fri Jan 23 04:34:56 PST 2015
```

Comment: Yes, I know that and I am using it because I have to support both Java dates and Joda-time dates.